# Can the Bishop select a player who discarded the Handmaid?

Tags: love-letter, love-letter-premium

In the premium edition of Love Letter, the player with the Bishop gets a heart if they correctly guess the card another player is holding. This doesn't directly affect the player being guessed upon, other than that they *may* discard their card, and that others get some information about that player's hand if they decide to keep it.

Can the player holding the bishop guess the hand of a player who is protected by the handmaid?

Comment: Edited title so that the answer isn't reversed from the question you ask at the end of your post.

Comment: `Discarded` in the title is technically correct, but can be vague - you could discard the handmaid due to a Prince forcing you to discard it, but you wouldn't benefit from her protection. Is there a better way to phrase this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the Bishop cannot guess the hand of a player who discarded the Handmaiden last turn.

This comes from the original rules:

> If all players other than the player whose turn it is are protected by Susannah, the player must choose him- or herself if possible.

This shows that the Handmaid doesn't only cause the player to not be affected, but it actually stops another player from choosing that player when choosing a player.

Also, having to reveal whether or not you hold a specific card is definitely being affected. If you are ignoring all effects from other players cards, then you would ignore the part where you must answer whether or not you have the guessed card.